# How to pass multiple parameters in columns.render function in Datatables jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have data below and I want to pass two variables (`id, name`) in the `columns.render` function in Datatables.

What I have now is only pass the `id` in the render function.
I also want to pass `name` in the render function.

Thanks.

```js
const myData = [
  { id: 2, name: "book" },
  { id: 5, name: "song" },
];

$("#example").DataTable({
  data: myData,
  columns: [
    {
      targets: 1,
      data: "id",
      render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return (
          "<button class='btn btn-default' data_id='" +
          data + //id is passed to here
          "'>" +
          "name" + //the name I want to pass to here.
          "</button>"
        );
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `row` parameter of `render` function.

```
const myData = [
  { id: 2, name: "book" },
  { id: 5, name: "song" },
];

$("#example").DataTable({
  data: myData,
  columns: [
    {
      targets: 1,
      data: "id",
      render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return (
          "<button class='btn btn-default' data_id='" +
          data + //id is passed to here
          "'>" +
          row.name + //get the name using row parameter
          "</button>"
        );
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

More details about render function can be found at https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't need to use the argument ```data```, I can only use ```row```  to access my data obejct then.

Comment: Yes, you can also use `row.id` instead of `data`